# Reading data from database in Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I have this class:

```
public class Student1
{
            public String Name { set; get; }
            public String Number { set; get; }

            public List<String> TakedCourses  { set; get; }

            public List<String> PassedCourses = new List<String>();
}
```

and I use Linq-to-SQL to save students to the database.

Now I want to search a name in database and add all  properties of this student to a new object of `Student`.

Like this:

```
Student s = new Student();
s = d.Students.Where(c => c.Name == cobStudents.SelectedItem.ToString()).Select(c => c);
```

it doesn't work and I don't know ho do this.

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `Select(c => c)` (which essentially returns the same collection that gets passed to it) with just `FirstOrDefault()` (which returns the first student in the collection or null if there is none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) it returns first matching element, Where returns all matching students *collection* ( not single element).

```
Student s = new Student(); 
s = d.Students.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name
== cobStudents.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

You can even use [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) if you are sure that condition true for only one element.

```
s = d.Students.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name
== cobStudents.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

And then you could access using...

```
if(s!= null)
{
       // access s here.
}
```

Comment: thanks, but It take error for ""Select": student does not contain a definition for select

Comment: Ahh.. I missed it, now you don't need `Select` any more.